# How to specify the required table when assigning a column to a variable in a blade

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the id of the grpusr table which is stored in the $jreq variable in the  following line :

```
<a href="{{ route('group.accept', ['id' =>$jreq->id])}}" class="btn btn-primary">Accept Joining request</a>
```

The following is the filling of $jreq  :

```
$j_request = DB::table('grpusrs')

            ->join('groups', 'grpusrs.group_id', '=', 'groups.id')
            ->join('users', 'grpusrs.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where('groups.owner_id', $user_id)
            ->where('grpusrs.join_request', 1)            
            ->get();

return view('profile.index')

        ->with('jreq', $j_request)
```

My problem is that each of the groups, users and grpusrs tables has an 'id'column, so how do I specify in the blade that I want the id of grpusrs table ?

Comment: You can specify on select or name alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **select()**

```
$j_request = DB::table('grpusrs')
            ->join('groups', 'grpusrs.group_id', '=', 'groups.id')
            ->join('users', 'grpusrs.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where('groups.owner_id', $user_id)
            ->where('grpusrs.join_request', 1) 
            ->select('grpusrs.*','groups.id as group_id','users.id as user_id')  // in here you have to use as for each columns anyway you will get  grpusrs.id in your response        
            ->get();
```